# How to read a text file and output it in html using python

Tags: python, html

Hey all I was learning python .I want to read a file(content.txt) and append the content of file to html which contains data in table format .

I have taken X1,X2,X3 as names and to know whether they have completed task or no I have written YES/NO/NA and comments.Instead of directly taking names in codes I want to write it in a content.txt file .

```
# write-html-2-windows.py

import webbrowser

f = open('helloworld.html','w')

message = """<html>
<h1> <style>
table.GeneratedTable {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ffcc00;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #000000;
}

table.GeneratedTable td, table.GeneratedTable th {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ffcc00;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 3px;
}

table.GeneratedTable thead {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}
</style>
 </h1>
<body><table class="GeneratedTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th> task </th>
      <th>comment </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>X1</td>
   <td> 
  <input type="radio" value ="YES"   >YES<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NO"  >NO<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NA"  >NA<br>

  <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" ><\td>

  <\td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X2</td>
  <td> 
  <input type="radio" value ="YES"  >YES<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NO"  >NO<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NA"  >NA<br>

  <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" ><\td>

  <\td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>X3</td>
  <td> 
  <input type="radio" value ="YES"   >YES<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NO"  >NO<br>
  <input type="radio"  value ="NA"  >NA<br>

  <td><input type="text" maxlength="100" ><\td>

  <\td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>"""

f.write(message)
f.close()

webbrowser.open_new_tab('helloworld.html')
```

I want to take names from a file called as content.txt and foreach of the values in content there should be task and comment .Please help me how can I poceed?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: what have you done so far for this? show us your code.

Comment: Look into the jinja2 framework

Comment: `pip install textile`

Comment: See here for example http://python.zirael.org/e-jinja2.html